# in regards to/regarding and of/from - Grammar in formal email

Tags: formality, email

I've been waiting for an email for several days and haven't heard of the other person yet. He emailed me, I answered him but I haven't heard back yet. I wish to send a message to remind him to answer me but I wish to know the correct way of putting it.

I am thinking of something like this:

I am writing in regards to/regarding your email of/from the 10th January 2019.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is correct: "with regards to," "in regards with," "regarding"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/which-is-correct-with-regards-to-in-regards-with-regarding) Or (on [English Language Learners]([English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/))) [For / from / of January 15, 1892?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115984/)

Comment: Hi AngloSpeaker, welcome to EL&U. If you have future questions, it's worth noting the advice from our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):  "Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!" For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score -1):

why don't you just say "I am writing further to your email on 10 January 2019 and my subsequent reply below. I would like to know when I should expect a answer.

Many thanks in advance,

XXXX

[include here the email chain]