# Romney, "regards to", and disfluency

Tags: meaning, phrases, errors

This is kind of a follow up to ["in regard to" or "in regards to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46917/in-regard-to-or-in-regards-to).

I have always considered that *regards to* means sending well wishes, while *regard to* means "concerning". Hence *with regards to* or *in regards to*, meaning "concerning", are erroneous and should be *with regard to* or *in regard to*.

Yet just looking at the recent Presidential debates, we have the following quotes from Governor Romney:

> And then, of course, *with regards to* standing for our principles, when -- when the students took to the streets in Tehran and the people there protested, the Green Revolution occurred, for the president to be silent I thought was an enormous mistake.

> The — the greatest failure we've had *with regards to* — to gun violence in some respects is what — what is known as Fast and Furious.

> Number two, *with regards to* Iraq, you and I agreed, I believe, that there should have been a status of forces agreement.

> And finally, *with regards to* that tax cut, look, I'm not looking to cut massive taxes and to reduce the -- the revenues going to the government.

> Well, President, you're -- Mr. President, you're absolutely right, which is that, *with regards to* 97 percent of the businesses are not -- not taxed at the 35 percent tax rate, they're taxed at a lower rate.

In all these cases, he means *concerning* and is not sending well wishes. Is this a Romney disfluency? Is this a regional variation? Is my intuition just completely wrong and this is generally accepted as standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a poor usage and had better be avoided. Here is what the American English Thesaurus has to say:

> As a noun in with regard to and in regard to, the **singular noun is correct**. **The plural form (as in with regards to and in regards to) is, to put it charitably, poor usage—e.g.**: “Single men and women are overwhelmed and confused by a barrage of information and advice on what to do and what not to do in regards to [read in regard to ] finding Mr. Right and Ms. Girl-of-My-Dreams.” ( Ebony; Dec. 1997) or “He became furious at the mere mention of ... the columnist who accused him recently of ‘judicial exhibitionism’ with regards to [read with regard to ] his trade-agreement ruling.” ( New York Times; Sept. 17, 1993.) The acceptable forms are best used as introductory phrases, but even these may be advantageously replaced by a single word such as concerning, regarding, or considering, or even in, about, or for.
>   Regards is acceptable as a verb in the phrase as regards, a traditional literary idiom (though now a little old-fashioned), and the past participle regarded commonly appears in two combinations: one, highly regarded, is a vague expression of praise; the other, widely regarded as, usually leads to words of praise—though it would certainly be possible to say that someone is “widely regarded as beneath contempt.” It is a mistake, however, to say widely regarded without as: “Crotty has published four novels since leaving the newspaper, and he's widely regarded [read highly regarded ] by both fiction writers and journalists.”.

Comment: Why the down vote? Before you click on that little *arrow*, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

"Is this a Romney disfluency? Is this a regional variation?"

No, it's neither. It's a typical error that becomes pervasive and eventually mainstream with repetition.

Such usages may become 'acceptable' in speech in course of time, though will never be correct in formal writing.

Comment: **will never be correct in formal writing.**  I'm sure the prescriptivists say that about all changes in the language.