# Is it correct to use "in regards to"?

Tags: grammaticality

I see many mentions of "in regards to" in written and spoken English...by native speakers...but the dictionary says "in regard to"..

Is it a matter of choice?

I checked several online dictionaries and all use "in regard to" and "with regard to"...but not "in regards to" or "with regards to"...

However, I see many English articles and native speakers using "regards"...so I was confused.

Comment: Hello, Taki. The phrases '[not] in the dictionary'; 'the dictionary says' are unhelpful in two ways. (1) They give the impression that you've checked in every English dictionary ever compiled, which is rarely true. (2) They don't tell readers which dictionaries to assume have already been checked rigorously, so as not to duplicate efforts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["In regard to" or "in regards to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46917/in-regard-to-or-in-regards-to)

Comment: Interestingly, in India, 'in regard to' is more common than in regards to.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why didn't you leave your answer there? It was completely on point.

Comment: @Lambie The question is clearly a duplicate. There are good answers at the original, one including the reference I reproduced.

Answer (score -1):

"In regards to" is a mistake that is gaining momentum at least in the U.S.

The correct phrase (meaning "concerning") is "in regard to".

Comment: It's normal to provide some evidence for your claims. You could reference grammars, dictionaries, or usage guides, or present statistical evidence based on your own research. You should also check and see if a question is a duplicate before answering.