# Which is the correct usage: "With regard to/with regards to" or "In regard to/in regards to?"

Tags: verbs, phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases

After reviewing answers found in the "Similar Questions" area, I didn't see a definitive answer.  To me it seems any writer or speaker is "regarding" something so the word "regard" would be singular.  The writer could be regarding several things, but this difference would not automatically dictate the word "regard" to be used in the plural, would it?

Comment: Related: 1) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/which-is-correct-with-regards-to-in-regards-with-regarding 2) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46917/in-regard-to-or-in-regards-to 3) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320/what-alternative-would-you-suggest-to-in-with-regards-to

Answer (score 3):

The correct usage is the singular *with (or in or having) regard to.*

> He made enquiries with regard to Beth.

Some people confuse the singular with the plural because there's a similar usage of the word *regard* in the plural form that is used to introduce a topic.

> As regards content, the programme will cover important current issues.

Source: ODE

Comment: This is a prescriptive sort of answer. Usage ultimately determines what is correct (people used to wail over the "incorrect usage" of *above* as an adjective, but it has stuck). With regards to the phrase at hand, see, et al., [the grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/regard-regards/) and [Daily writing tips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/in-regards-to/). The *Oxford English Dictionary* says the plural forms are "regional and nonstandard", but it does this from a descriptive point of view; and it is not the same as incorrect. It would also be nice if you included a link to the ODE.

Comment: The usual way is 'with regard to'. Also used are: as for, regarding, as regards, (not as regard). For example, in "With regard to your membership request...." with regard is interchangeable with as for, as regards, regarding.

Answer (score 0):

I had benefited from the discussions here. Recently I came across some useful source in a reference book and I would like to share it as well.

> **with regards to** The traditional expressions are 'with regard to', 'in regard to', and 'as regards'. The bastard phrase 'with regards
> to', which marries 'with regard to' and 'give my regards to Broadway',
> is displacing the first two of these in popular use. Sticklers will
> cleave to 'with regard to' and will surely flee screaming from 'in
> regard on', as used in this extract from a strikingly bad business
> email: 'I have been put in contact with you in regards on getting a
> quote of cost for you guys to plain English read a A4 leaflet with
> information front and back.' Help.

Martin Cutts. *Oxford Guide to Plain English*, 4th Edition, p.44.